# swift3 string to Selector,how to receive return value

Tags: swift, swift3

```
var tweakEntries = [(title : String, array : [Array<String>])]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    navigationItem.title = "设置"
    //tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    let timeSettingArr = [
        ["工作时间间隔","workTime","setWorkTime"],
        ["休息时间间隔","relaxTime","setRelaxTime"],
    ]
    let _ = [
        ["通知标题","",""],
        ["通知语","",""]
    ]
    let _ = [
        ["显示背景图片","displayStatus","setDisplayStatus"]
    ]
    tweakEntries = [
        ("时间设置",timeSettingArr),
        //("通知设置",localNoti),
        //("其他设置",otherSettingArr)
    ]
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let section = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row
    let identifier  = "SettingCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = SettingCell.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = tweakEntries[section].array[row][0]
    let methodName = tweakEntries[section].array[row][1];
    print("\(methodName)")
    let method : Selector = Selector(methodName)
    let detailText = perform(method)
    //let temp : CGFloat = detailText as! CGFloat
    //cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(temp)"


    return cell!
}

func workTime() -> CGFloat {
    return 11.0
}
```

how to receive return value

perform :

```
public func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

use tuple make code easier to expand

tableView delegateMethod and dataSouseMethod according to the tuple returnValue

must use perform? Whether there is other func

code: https://github.com/CoderYLZhang/Working

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492033/return-value-for-performselector as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680609/selector-and-return-value     These are obj-c examples but you'll get the drift.  In summary; use delegate pattern.

Comment: Please try to explain what you really want to do. `perform` is not a global function, are you assuming all that code are somewhere in a class? And this part `let detailText = ...` strongly suggest the result of `perform(method)` would be a String, but you are showing a method which returns `CGFloat`. Anything in your question does not specify what you really want to do. Not many readers go deep inside a github repository.

Comment: @OOPer sorry,i had supply some info

Comment: Simply, getting floating point value from `perform` may not be possible. You need to find other ways to handle it like returning `NSNumber` rather than `CGFloat`.

Comment: @Yohst first ,thx, but in ObjC, perform returnValue type is id,in swift,returnValue type is Unmanaged<AnyObject>!, so my code in OC is OK,swift is error